# Automating a Function in Python which runs requests to different Langchain Agents - It oftens gets stuck

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I am trying to run a function in python that takes in a specific input and based on that, runs requests to two different langchain agents (create_pandas_dataframe_agent & ChatOpenAI).

I can provide a snippet of the code below. The problem is, the Agent tends to get stuck at random moments and takes forever to process, while other times it is very fast and simple. Is it something wrong with the way I am writing the code? Should I clean the data better? What can be done?

```
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(ChatOpenAI(temperature=0),
        df, verbose=True,
        agent_type=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
        max_execution_time=3,
        early_stopping_method="generate")

llm_talkative = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0,
                       model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                           max_tokens= 1000)

def envr_trend_analysis(district):
    #Calculate the Environmental Score Trend Over Time
  cs_env_prompt = "What is the current environmental score for district of " + str(district) + "?"
  cs_env = agent.run(cs_env_prompt)

  env_prompt = "What is the percentage increase for the 'environmental score' in the district of " + str(district) + " for each year."
  percentage_increase = agent.run(env_prompt)

  new_prompt = str(cs_env) + "Explain if this is good or bad? If the score is 75, then this is a sign of a healthy environment. If the score is score below 30, then the environment may be at risk. If the score is between 35 and 70, then the environment is performing moderately. " + str(percentage_increase) + " \n Describe this in words. Explain what it means."

  #Describe the trend
  messages = [
      SystemMessage(content=system_prompt),
      HumanMessage(content=new_prompt)
  ]

  response_environmental =llm_talkative(messages)

  return response_environmental.content
```

I am expecting to be able to provide the function with different districts and automate the outputs to be able to save them.